# Same number of generators and coincidence of integral closures of ideals ensures equality?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a commutative, Noetherian regular local ring with infinite residue field $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$. When $I$ is an ideal of $R$ there is the well-known *integral closure* $\bar{I}$ of $I$ consisting of elements $s\in R$ satisfying monic equations $s^n+a_1 s^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n=0$ with $a_j\in I^j$, $j=1,\ldots,n$.

A subideal $J\subset I$ is said to be a *reduction* of $I$ if there exists $t\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $JI^t=I^{t+1}$. It is also well-known that $J\subset I$ is a reduction of $I$ if and only if $\bar{I}=\bar{J}$ (equality of integral closures). Reductions can be proper: for instance, if $R=k[[x,y]]$ then $(x^2,y^2)$ is a proper (non-trivial) reduction of $(x^2,xy,y^2)$.

My question could be phrased as (EDITED): Are there any general conditions under which $\bar{I}=\bar{J}$ ensures equality of the original ideals $J\subset I$, when the ideals $I$ and $J$ have the same number of generators? Suppose it is known that the ideal $J\,\,$ I'm interested in is not a minimal (regarding the $\subseteq$ order...) reduction of $I$. As far as I understand this last condition could be concisely put in terms of anaytic spread $\ell(I)$ of $I$: that is $\mu(J)=\mu(I)>\ell(I)$.

To avoid trivial answers assume also that the ideals are not integrally closed. If it matters, the $R=k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ would be enough to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have a positive answer in the case where the residue field is infinite and $J$ is a minimal reduction.

In this case, $J$ is a minimal reduction of $I$ if and only if the number of generators of $J$ is equal to $\ell$, the analytic spread of $I$. Furthermore, the minimal generating set of $J$ can be extended to that of $I$, See Prop 8.3.3 in Integral closures by Swanson-Huneke. The example following the proposition shows that in general, the equality on the number of generators does not imply equality.

Comment: The minimality condition was what I meant to avoid when included $\mu>\dim R$. But now, reading your answer, I realized that the correct condition to be put in should be $\mu>\ell(I)$. I apologize... Going to edit the question. In any case the example in the book occurs inside a non regular ring, which still give me some hope.

Comment: I missed the regular condition. You can take $I = (x^4,x^2y^2,y^4)$ and $J = (x^4,x^3y^2,y^4)$. Both contain the minimal reduction $(x^4,y^4)$ and have the ideal generated by all the monomial of  degree $4$ as their integral closure.

Comment: Cool. No hope anymore. If you could put this as an answer I will gladly accept it.